# SSRS Report Switch Datasource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS reports and now I want to change data-source base on parameter. I had all ready tried to create a dynamic data source base on parameter and it works perfect on our local environment. But on production we are not able connect database due to security issue.

To overcome the security issue. we had created two data source "ProdDB" and "ArchDB" in reporting server and map with my report's data source

Now I want to know how we can Switch data source base on parameter like 
Report parameter @dbsource = "Prod"

```
if @dbsource.value = "Prod" then 
  datasource = "ProdDB
Else 
  DataSource = "ArchDB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

1. Create two report parameters as databaseName and DatabaseServer

[image]

2. in datasource-> properties -> connection String -> expression write a connection string as below

`="Data Source=" + Parameters!databaseServer.Value + ";Initial Catalog=" + Parameters!databaseName.Value`

This will ask database name and database server as a report parameters, if you are running the report as data driven subscriptions you can pass these parameters dynamically from a query or static subscription parameters.

Comment: i had already tried this way but our production team is not agree with the solution due to security issue. as we are working with the banking sector so we can not take a risk.

Comment: other option is adding code to a report. check how to add code to report in below link    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs    . write a code to return your database details. this way your database details will embedded in code and will be secure. with code you can explore more with security perspective as using configuration file for database details...

Comment: @DeepakBhise, Can you please have a look and suggest the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057914/switch-datasources-in-ssrs

Comment: @Chirag, Can you please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057914/switch-datasources-in-ssrs